# Insertion at index of LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

Hi I have this method to insert an element at any index of the LinkedList, however, the new element is not showing in the output, what did i miss thanks!
I have showed partial code below, any help is greatly appreciated!

```
public class LinkedList<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Iterable<E>
{
    // instance data members of list
    private Node head; // reference to the first node
    private int N;     // number of elements stored in the list

    private class Node
    {
        // instance data members of Node
        public E item;
        public Node next;

        // constructors for Node
        public Node()
        {
            item = null;  next = null;
        }

        public Node(E e, Node ptr)
        {
            item = e;  next = ptr;
        }
    }// end class Node

    public void insertAfter(int k, E e){
        if (k < 0 || k >= size()){
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();}
        Node temp=new Node();
        temp.item=e;
        int index=k-1;
        Node current=head;
        for (int i=0; i<=N; N++){
            if (i==index){
                temp.next=current.next;
                current.next=temp;
            }
        }
        ++N;  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not moving the current element throught the list. You loop the integer indexes but don't move the pointer to the current node. So in the loop **current** is always the head of the linked list. 
You need to make it like that:

```
for (int i=0; i<=N; N++)
        if (i==index){
            temp.next=current.next;
            current.next=temp;
        }else{
         current=current.next;
       }
```

This way when you add the element you will be in the proper position. Otherwise you will ways insert it in the first position.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're incrementing an instance variable `N`

Try this instead

```
public void insertAfter(int k, E e){
    if (k < 0 || k >= size()){
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();}
    Node temp=new Node();
    temp.item=e;
    int index=k-1;
    Node current=head;
    for (int i=0; current != null && i<N; i++){
        if (i==index){
            temp.next=current.next;
            current.next=temp;
        } else {
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    ++N;  
}
```

Don't forget that if you insert a node at position 0, you need to update what `head` references.

Comment: Thank u so much! how did i miss that ...haha